# Tesnorflow: How to provide your own `sampled_values` for tf.nn.sampled_softmax_loss?

Tags: python, tensorflow

In tf.nn.sampled_softmax_loss, one of the optional inputs is to put your own samples values. I would like to provide my own samples values so that I can use float16 (half precision) variables. If `sampled_values` is left blank, Tensorflow will use `log_uniform_candidate_sampler` to get values, which can only return float32.

Here are all the inputs.

```
tf.nn.sampled_softmax_loss(
    weights,
    biases,
    labels,
    inputs,
    num_sampled,
    num_classes,
    num_true=1,
    sampled_values=None,
    remove_accidental_hits=True,
    partition_strategy='mod',
    name='sampled_softmax_loss',
    seed=None
)
```

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/sampled_softmax_loss

This is the information they give for the sampled_values arg :

> sampled_values: a tuple of (sampled_candidates, true_expected_count,
>   sampled_expected_count) returned by a *_candidate_sampler function.
>   (if None, we default to log_uniform_candidate_sampler)

I'm trying to figure out how to provide this tuple. What exactly are the `sampled_candidates`, `true_expected_count`, `sampled_expected_count` ?

I know that it's sampling the weights and corresponding biases, so do I put them together in it's own tuple for `sampled_candidates` ? Also, am I putting the int for the place of the weight in the matrix, or am I putting the whole embedding itself?

I've also looked at Tensorflow's math supplimental on negative sampling but I couldn't find any information for my issue https://www.tensorflow.org/extras/candidate_sampling.pdf

In my search, I found this very similar question on a google forum

https://groups.google.com/a/tensorflow.org/forum/#!topic/discuss/6IDJ-XAIb9M

The Answer given is

> `sampled_values` is the tuple returned by our *candidate_sampler
>   classes. These classes implement methods that sample contrastive
>   labels (not observed, but used during training) according to some
>   distribution Q for use in approximate training methods like
>   noise-contrastive estimation (NCE) and Sampled Softmax. An example is
>   the log_uniform_candidate_sampler, which samples labels according to
>   the log-uniform distribution.
>
> You almost never need to provide these yourself. You would simply pass
>   in the result of a call to a *candidate_sampler function in the tf.nn
>   module (where * can be "uniform", "log_uniform", "zipfian_binned",
>   etc), e.g.
>
> sampled_values = tf.nn.zipfian_binned_candidate_sampler(...)
>
> If you just want to get it to work, just leave it to None, and it
>   would default to the log_uniform_candidate_sampler (often a good
>   choice).
>
> If you are interested in the math behind this, see this document:
>   https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.8/extras/candidate_sampling.pdf.
>
> But to answer your question: For each batch of observed labels L, and
>   a candidate sampling distribution Q, the tuple consists of:
>
> - the tensor with the actual sampled contrastive labels N,
> - the tensor with the log-expected-values of the observed labels L under Q, i.e. log Q(L), and
> - the tensor with the log-expected values of the contrastive labels under Q, i.e. log Q(N).
>
> The latter are required for the math to go through (see above
>   document). So sampled_values contains(with a hopefully clear abuse of
>   notation):
>
> sampled_values = (N, log Q(L), log Q(N)).

However, I still don't know how to input a value. I'm not sure what the datatypes should be, and if N is the int place in the embedding matrix, or the embedding itself. Also, I'm guessing N should be a list of values itself, the size of the number of negative labels we have to sample.

I was wondering if I could get a example with some values. For example, for a negative sampling of 3, do I do something like this?

sampled_values = ([4,29, 12], [1, 1, 1], [0, 0, 0])

Also, the documentation says that the tuple should be " returned by a *_candidate_sampler function"

Does that mean I need to provide a function that returns the tuple, instead of the tuple itself?